# Connection timeout trying to connect with sencha app

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

I am working on Sencha Touch application which is working perfectly in localhost within the same network. When i tried to move my server code to production server, i can't able to connect with my app via mobile data as well as wifi.

In server side, there was no issue. I copied the url and hits in browser i can able to get valid response. But in server side log its showing connection timeout error. Any suggestion ?

Comment: What is the timeout set in the proxy used by store..

Comment: Yeah i added even i make it as 30000. Still i am not getting response. but its shows status code as 200 in DeveloperTool (Network)

Comment: Have you tried to ping www.myapponserver.com or 192.xxx.yyy.zzz/myawesomeapp/index.html ? Doesn't sound like a Sencha or code related issue but purely of networking

Comment: @code4jhon Its network issue. The production server cant able to find the domain name. I fixed the issue by configure the System32 environmental variable. Thanks guys.

Comment: I'm glad to hear you fixed it, regards.